# Tensorflow Conv3D with variable input size

Tags: keras, tensorflow, convolutional-neural-network

I have a hypotethical question: Is it possible to train Conv3D with variable input size?

Sample dim = Length x Width x Depth ; Depth are fixed per each samples, let's say 500. However Length x Width can vary, e.g.:

```
Sample 1 = 50 x 4 x 500
Sample 2 = 7 x 7 x 500
Sample 3 = 10 x 13 x 500
.....
Sample n = 5 x 32 x 500
```

These are for classification problems, the next class could have a different sample size, e.g.:

```
Sample 4 = 6 x 8 x 500 (from class 2)
Sample 5 = 3 x 32 x 500 (from class 2)
....
Sample m = 10 x 11 x 500 (also from class 2)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Keras, you should specify the shape of your inputs and that shape should be fixed. Then you probably have to somehow resize all of your samples to a fix size $m \times n \times 500$.

You can use similar ideas in image resizing (e.g. interpolation, Nearest-neighbor interpolation, Bilinear and bicubic algorithms, Box Sampling, ...).

Comment: That's the problem. It's not an image but an audio data. Hence image resizing wouldn't make sense here. Is there any possible way to use different input size in Tensorflow? I know in Keras it has to be specified - but how about Tensorflow or PyTorch?

Comment: @user2754279 what is the nature of your samples? Is there any way to convert all samples to a unique-shape samples? For example for each samples and each depth, you can embed the average, maximum, minimum and train your model with 3x500 samples.

Comment: It's high-frequency time-series. So, e.g. pixel x1,y1 contains time-series with a length of 500 data-points. The depth (500 data points) are the same until xm, yn and this is true for all samples. However 'm' and 'n' might be different for each sample.

Comment: Another thing is: there is a local connectivity between the neighboring pixels. For instance in area of x10;y10, x11;y11, x10;y13, x12;y10, x9;y12 shares a similar properties. That is the depth value within these pixel clusters are small changing but in gradual way. But if we're looking into far away located pixel, e.g. x50;y85 or x58;y76 then the depth value might be completely far away from the above-mentioned clusters. I am thinking YOLO-v2 or v3 might be able to train this kind of data - but I am not sure. What do you suggest?